# Saving MediaRecorder output in a format that can be shared on Whatsapp

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video-capture, whatsapp, web-mediarecorder

I'm working on a website that records video with [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder), and I found that my Chrome on Mac supports multiple WEBM recording formats for

```
new MediaRecorder(videoStream, { mimeType: ... })
```

like

ad

and also MKV formats like `video/x-matroska`, `video/x-matroska;codecs=h264`.

I added a listener to the `dataavailable` events that collects the data to an array named `mediaChunks`, and after stopping the media-recorder I can call `URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(mediaChunks, { type: ... }))` with several output formats.

Finally, to download the file, I create an link element ('a' tag) and can configure the filename extension when I set its `download` field to `filename.mkv`, `filename.webm`, `filename.mp4`.

Is there any configuration of a recording-format + output-format + filename-extension that will create a file that can be shared and viewed on WhatsApp? Will it be viewable both on iPhones and Android devices?

There are so many formats & codecs, but none of what I've tried seems to work. I have to refer my users to one of the format-conversion websites (like zamzar.com), or start building a heavy backend.

It's 2019, surely there should be a simple way to resolve this...

Comment: sorry for the bad edit, from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I've found MediaRecorder only supports webm video containers at least on firefox. They'll need to be converted to another container type to be played far and wide.

Answer (score -1):

`video/mp4` can be specified in the mime-type, and can be used by WhatsApp.